# Erro ao fazer upload de imagem no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload

Estou tentando fazer upload de uma imagem em um site geranciado com Wordpress e está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

*O arquivo está vazio. Faça o upload de algo mais substancial. Esse erro também pode ter acontecido se os uploads estiverem desativados no seu php.ini ou se a definição de post_max_size for menor que a do upload_max_filesize no php.ini.*

Alguém já passou por isso? Já criei um arquivo php.ini na raiz e informei

```
upload_max_filesize = 30M
post_max_size = 30M
max_execution_time = 300
```

e não resolveu

Verifiquei que no cpanel o espaço em disco está cheio, será que é isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Resolvido. O problema era quota de disco.

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza deve ser o espaço em disco primeiramente tente reduzir o espaço em disco e caso não resolva tente criar um código em php simples que faz upload para testar se é uma configuração do servidor que esta dando este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Dê permissões de escrita ao usuário do servidor web na pasta `wp-content/uploads/`.

Comment: Amigo, apliquei 777 de permissões e não rolou =/ acho que é quota de disco mesmo.

Comment: Agora que eu notei o uso da cota. Não tem como diminuir o uso esvaziando os temporários ou algo do tipo?